# How to fit image based on div size in html

Tags: html, css

How can I make an image fit a whole div (resizing the image if necessary)?

Comment: Question is duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a 'div' container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, You can use

```
  width: auto;
  height: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
```

Instead of cover you can use contain, fill, etc as per your choice.

Comment: Thank you, Exactly what i want!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot always display with the same dimensions
Because your container may be other sizes
But the normal way is to set the height to 100% and hide it overflow
Or vice versa
width: 100%

or use object-fit: hover
same as:

```
img { 
     width:100%; 
     height:100%; 
     object-fit:cover; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the **height OR width of DIV in %**, then the div will be expanded as per the size of the image but if you provide the **width and height of the div in pixle "px"** then the div will have fixed height and width.