# How do I get the most out of image for responsive layout using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to make an image good for a responsive layout. I am using an large .svg image at the moment which resizes to any and still looks sharp.

However, when I put the image in a div it is sometime too big or small. I just want it to fill the screen properly.

So far I have coded:

```
img{display:block;}
```

but am sure theres more to it...Anyone?

Comment: width, min-width , max-width + % can help you here

Comment: The min and max seem important. What are they supposed to do?

Comment: Set the minimum width and maximum width the image is allowed to expand / contract to.

Comment: Hiya, Your title doesn't make it clear what you're really asking. Please edit that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a 'div' container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your image change size dynamically (and stay within your div), give it a max width and set the height to auto.

```css
.imgcontain {
  max-width: 50%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class=imgcontain>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542044896530-05d85be9b11a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Transformer - No problem. Glad to hear!

Comment: Hang on...I created a container with a 1px black border...put the tags inside the container...tried centering another image using margin-left, margin-right: auto but the image goes over the border line (it doesn't resize). What am I doing wrong...and how did it work for the .svg file and not the .jpg file?

Comment: @Transformer - I can't be exactly sure without looking at your markup, but it sounds like you're trying to center it and keep it within a parent container that is not responsive. Also, for auto margin centering to work, you'll have to re-add `display: block;`. My apologies for omitting that. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/jjsecord/sp205xft/6/

Comment: Tried this: .main-sub{max-width:550px; border: 1px solid white;}.img{max-width: 50%;height:auto;  display:block; margin: 0 auto;}....didnt work

Comment: @Transformer - Can you link a live example of your code please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hm087ster/9vxdjo5m/4/ (Edit: realised the mistake...had .img{} instead of img{})

Comment: @Transformer - Great. Pesky mistakes like that are seriously the worst. Hours of time to find a simple period..*facepalm*. I read that code like three times and still didn't catch it! Hahah. Be sure to mark the answer correct for others searching.

Comment: in addition, if I want to "crop" a photo from the top a bit (just a few pixels) how would I do this with css? (max-height: 99%; overflow:hidden; is not the way I assume).

Comment: @Transformer - If I understand correctly, just add `padding-top:3px;` to `img{}`.

Comment: I want to crop it...(thats a challenge)

Comment: Is object-fit the only answer??

Comment: @Transformer - If you position the image using `position: absolute;` or `position:fixed`, I suppose you can play around with the clip property. I recommend just cropping your image before uploading it to your site though.