# Making Image Responsive

Tags: css, image, responsive

I am trying to make my logo image responsive on my page. I used the created a responsive class and in the stylesheet set the width of that class to max-width 100%, but the image still isn't scaling when I resize the browser.

HTML part:

```html
<div align="center" class="div3">
    <img src="http://www.revolutionvinyl.net/rvgglitch.gif" width="700" 
    height="700" class="responsive" alt="RVG Logo"> 
</div>
```

CSS part:

```css
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block; 
    height: auto;
}
```

Thank you in advance! This site has been driving me crazy, so this fix will help out a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a 'div' container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container)

Comment: Yes it is. I was still having issues with the image being too big, this corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting an explicit, hard width of `700px` on the `img`, which negates what you were aiming for with the `max-width: 100%`. If you want the image to keep scaling, but *not* beyond the viewport, try this instead:

```css
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" class="div3"><img src="http://www.revolutionvinyl.net/rvgglitch.gif" class="responsive" alt="RVG Logo"> </div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hy46k1aq/1/)

Comment: Thanks Andy! Took a bit of work since Dreamweaver wouldn't save that bit of code in the stylesheet no matter how many times I tried saving the file, but I got around it by just adding a style tag to the image HTML. Had to change the width to 700 as well while keeping the max at 100% to achieve my desired look. You just saved me even more frustration. Learning this whole CSS thing as I go has been a lot harder than I expected, but I'm slowly catching on.