# How to adjust image dimensions within parent container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to adjust the image dimensions after uploading it. Let's assume my uploaded image originally has 450x700 dimensions and its parent container has 400x400 dimensions. In my case, I use `object-fit` to fit image its parent container by preserving aspect ratio and it looks like

[image]

But I need to show image fully and `object-fit` is not the right option for this case. Removing `object-fit` and adding `width` and `height` with `100%` makes it fully visible, meanwhile decreasing the quality. Here it looks like

[image]

[image]

In the last image the original image is this

[image]

**UPDATED**

Actually, I can solve it with `object-fit: contain`, but it's not 100 percent right for me or maybe there is no other way. With contain, I get this

[image]

You can notice the white background of the image, which doesn't come well with background color of the container (which is light gray). Is there any possibility to solve it?

Comment: if you are using img tag, you can try using all the three properties height: 100%; width: 100% and object-fit: cover

Answer (score 2):

When you say `object-fit` doesn't work, is that because it's cropping the image? And did you try changing `object-fit: cover` to `object-fit: contain`?

Another option is to have the image as a background image, and set [background size](https://cssreference.io/property/background-size/) to `contain` too. This will scale the image to fit within the bounds accordingly. e.g.

```css
.image__wrapper {
    background: url(../your-img.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Unfortunately, stretching the image to fit will always distort and therefore degrade the image.

Comment: If the background of the image is always white, you can just set a background colour to the parent wrapper (e.g. `background-color: white`)

Answer (score 1):

you can use css property..

```
background: url('images_here')no-repeat center center
 background-size: cover (or) contain
 width:400px;
 height: 400px;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full image to be visible you should use `object-fit: contain`, see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.contain {object-fit: contain;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The object-fit Property</h1>

<h2>object-fit: contain:</h2>
<img class="contain" src="SOMEFILENAME.jpg" alt="Paris" style="width:200px"> <!--Put the restricting size value here-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use pictures with alpha channels (such as png) or use svgs. Another way is to set the parents background to white as well.

Answer (score 1):

> image-parent assume this is your parent container class.so you can add css like this

```css
.image-parent img{
    height:400px;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If its image tag you can set `object-fit:contain` along with height and width and if its background image you can set `background-size:contain`

Comment: This is only possible if you edit images before upload else you have to scarifies one thing either full image with image cut or contain image with background. The other hack is use some color class to fill background with you image background but that not possible for you when unknown images uploaded @NorayrGhukasyan

Comment: Pleasure is all mine @NorayrGhukasyan but i suggest you to visit the ans of KEVIN in this link may be that help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container