# How to adjust images in the box without starch using css?

Tags: html, css, image

I have three types of images with different height and width.

Now what I am doing is, I have to display all with equal height and width.

***Note: I don't want to use a background image. I am getting images form database***

**Snippet 1**

I tried `box` with `height` and `width:300px` and img `height:auto` but images are not displaying with equal.

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://cdn2.expertreviews.co.uk/sites/expertreviews/files/styles/er_main_wide/public/2019/03/best-external-hard-drive-sandisk_extreme_ssd.jpg?itok=aIFHiCLL">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1576973630537-dd588987df10?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/712xVgJWSbL._SX466_.jpg">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Snippet 2**

I tried with `height: 100%; object-fit: cover;` to the img tag but in this images are displaying big in the box.

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://cdn2.expertreviews.co.uk/sites/expertreviews/files/styles/er_main_wide/public/2019/03/best-external-hard-drive-sandisk_extreme_ssd.jpg?itok=aIFHiCLL">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1576973630537-dd588987df10?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/712xVgJWSbL._SX466_.jpg">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My expected output is
[image]

Would you help me out?

Comment: You can still use background image with contain even you're getting the image from database.

Comment: Yes, I know can use it but I don't want to use a background image.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for you. Here is the [Demo](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/oNgwgKV). You left `image` is the main issue. Left `image` haven't **white space** in `top` and `bottom` so you are confuse that `image` isn't placed in centre `vertically` and `horizontally`.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="center-image" src="https://cdn2.expertreviews.co.uk/sites/expertreviews/files/styles/er_main_wide/public/2019/03/best-external-hard-drive-sandisk_extreme_ssd.jpg?itok=aIFHiCLL">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1576973630537-dd588987df10?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/712xVgJWSbL._SX466_.jpg">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Add a specific `class` for left `image`(When you want to `center` image vertically and horizontally). I add here `.center-image`.

**CSS**

```
*,
*:after,
*:before{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: outside none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 -15px;
}
ul:not(:last-child){
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul li {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
}
/* Images parent global CSS */
ul li .box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #888888;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
/* Global image CSS */
.box img {
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
/* Specific image or center image CSS */
.box img.center-image{
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

> Hope this help!

Comment: How you assign center-image class? when you are getting images from the database?

Comment: If you aren't able to add `center-image` `class` then you have to insert correct image  that will fit in box. I just showing you how you get desire result.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using flex-box. Don't know if it is a problem  for you. But it works for me.

The idea is to make your `ul` flex. Inside you seem to want to have `ul li` as `display: inline-box;` so I kept this as a requirement (but not necessary).

This way your `.box` allow to center the images in the middle of your div.

Then, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container) was helping to have the right size of your images.

Here is the final css code :

```css
    ul {
      display: flex;
    }

    ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .box {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: auto;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    img {
      margin: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>
    <div class="box">
   <img src="https://cdn2.expertreviews.co.uk/sites/expertreviews/files/styles/er_main_wide/public/2019/03/best-external-hard-drive-sandisk_extreme_ssd.jpg?itok=aIFHiCLL">
  </div>
 </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1576973630537-dd588987df10?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
   </div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="box">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/712xVgJWSbL._SX466_.jpg">
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Can you share the snippet? because I tried your code I am getting the output like  https://prnt.sc/qf5og4

Comment: Sorry this is kinda new to me. Can you detail what you expect from me ?

Comment: I added my expected output in the question at the end of the question.

Comment: Yes you are right I see the difference between your output and mine.

The problem is that my solution preserve aspect ratio. Your goal doesn't. It's ok but we'll need your strategy here.

Do we agree that width should be truncated in any cases (we first adapt height at 100%, and truncate width if needed)  ?

Comment: @Naren Verma : In such case (we put height at 100% and truncate width if needed) I don't see how we can deal with the first image (scan disk). 

Indeed, there are almost no margin on top and bottom of this picture.

If that is not a problem : 

`.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}`

will do the trick

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Give me some time to check this

Comment: No problems ;) merry Christmas by the way

Comment: Also, I am planning to show images with an aspect ratio.   Thank you very much and Merry Christmas you too.

Comment: Happy new year. So is my solution clear enough for you? or do you need clarifications?

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul  {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box1
{
  background: url('https://cdn2.expertreviews.co.uk/sites/expertreviews/files/styles/er_main_wide/public/2019/03/best-external-hard-drive-sandisk_extreme_ssd.jpg?itok=aIFHiCLL')no-repeat center center;
  background-size : contain;
}
.box2
{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1576973630537-dd588987df10?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80')no-repeat center center;
  background-size : contain;
}
.box3
{
  background: url('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/712xVgJWSbL._SX466_.jpg')no-repeat center center;
  background-size : contain;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="box1 box">
    
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box2 box">
    
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box3 box">
   
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Am using `background-image` and `flex-layout`. Try something like this

```css
ul  {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box1
{
  background: url('https://cdn2.expertreviews.co.uk/sites/expertreviews/files/styles/er_main_wide/public/2019/03/best-external-hard-drive-sandisk_extreme_ssd.jpg?itok=aIFHiCLL')no-repeat center center;
  background-size : contain;
}
.box2
{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1576973630537-dd588987df10?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80')no-repeat center center;
  background-size : contain;
}
.box3
{
  background: url('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/712xVgJWSbL._SX466_.jpg')no-repeat center center;
  background-size : contain;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="box1 box">
    
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box2 box">
    
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box3 box">
   
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't want to use background image. and it's not my expected output