# HTML Change Image Size

Tags: html, css

HTML Change Image Size Depending on Mobile/Desktop View

Beside using bootstrap , is there any way to change the image size depending on mobile/desktop view ?

Comment: you can set the height and width of the image according to the screen size

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a 'div' container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either set your image width and height using %, or, better, use [CSS Media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) so you can have rules based on the viewport width, for example

Comment: Thanks for the help , this is the one i will use and it works !

Comment: You're wecome @greenboxgoolu, once you understand them media queries are super easy

Answer (score 1):

You use meta viewport tag so and set the width and height of the image to 100%

Comment: Thanks for the help , saw the method .

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to show your element differently via device size, the best way i think is using `media query`.

in bootstrap you might have saw keywords like `sm`, `md` or `lg`. they are all based on media query. you can find how they work on following link
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

the second way is render two element for each device and show each item on the targeted devices. with notation would be easy

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/display/#notation

Comment: Thanks for the help , but i will use another method

Comment: @greenboxgoolu using media query is what i recommend ;) gl

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/86arOE_jc_FYR6_mPbeXrzWB4LwvgCRWPGXbbftgG4_zAjY05ajbmq3xiG0Xc_uYCoTccikGvLdo5WIlofH5pmySn1VRejqngh2pwDLquiLJYayCOJKUrZKFnOwmSxKzQqqOM1y5o42TPk6LYR1vbPjrEPx3dQIUEwS4IPRjzt3JdPZT32TkqCECm-PoQtsBAPnyN6g46PbiyD9fblgzuBcT2xuO1AaZgOkR53bom8ATCBkDgcYT_mnsxWuxLGp6cNFUR4lWBFKyYkYJWJY--KmIVCWDDoJ3SxwjimGjwRG-X2Qu3AP4wa6tRazHuBo3a8IOofm6f5arSRdpVy4AaXoacTPz8TSkcofA0YaIttHpek1Gi5v1yMSbi5mHV6Mfv4lyczXPp8c5iNR7IFPvgMz1BiCETTxNwSvDjb2JCN94_256Fzejrs-Dk-kMYeCCYQh2Zd_lt9xiEQDgZ5gufdpxxM9xDiP447vrOqKbBMcAS_6hu43EwRi97ILAhBpS3QLP-4WhKf4GHauWqML_EcBvhszB-6T1iGeCWvpAT9jZVDVgekalBvLZiZNoy5Ow9QlnHA=w1827-h711-no' width="460" height="345">
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how the image will scale.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```