# How do I fix this css problem with the header on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with my logo on the mobile screen. It's too big and doesn't fit properly inline. Please help. I have attached what it looks like now and what it should look like. You can check the website [here](http://www.rockstarbargains.com).

Before/Now:

[image: Text]

After (how it should look):

[image: Text]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link to your site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) or any other third party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could play with the `max-width` parameter of the logo setting also `height: auto` that way you can control the maximum size of the logo.

I tried modifying your code and what worked for me was

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #header .header-main .custom-html img {
        max-width: 45vw;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

The vw units represent viewport width percentage, so it's a variable unit, based on the viewport width.

I would prefer fixing a size though to avoid it look strange on different cell phones.