# Fit image-width to length of span element?

Tags: html, css

I have a div `inline-block` that contains an `image` and a `span` element.

This is the markup:

```
<div class="inline-box">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/22/15/25/fetch-4957501__340.jpg">
    <span class="text">Hallo XYZ</span>
</div>
```

This is the outcome:

[image]

I would like that the image has the same size as the span element and thus the surrounding inline-block should also have the size of the span element.

So this is what I would like to have:

[image]

Is it possible with pure CSS? The markup can be changed. Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Elenktik/cb6r3shq/).

Enclosure: I know that one can make an image fit a fixed-size div with

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
object-fit: contain;
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container). However, the here mentioned div has no fixed size, so it won't work.

Comment: width:0;min-width:100% to the image (the duplicate is doing the opposite but the technique remain the same) https://jsfiddle.net/hkwgc8pn/

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you! I was sure this question was out there, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @j08691 seems like it is actually possible! :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Nice