# How to make image fit device in wagtail

Tags: image, wagtail

I have a banner image on my page and I wish to fill the page width. What's the correct way to do this in Wagtail?

I have

```
{% image page.banner_image fill-1110x300 as img %}
```

and that looks good on a PC, but it is far too wide on a a phone

How can make the image resize to fit the device?

Comment: Use any of the CSS-based solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container - having Wagtail in the mix doesn't really change anything here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link in @gasman's comment provided the basis of my solution.

**xxx.html**

```
    {% image page.banner_image scale-100 as img %}
    <img src="{{ img.url }}" alt="{{ img.alt }}" class="responsive">
```

**xxx.css**

```
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

This displays an image that fills the browser horizontally and adjusts its height proportionally