# How to resize an image for smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries, image-resizing

I am trying to resize an image so that it displays appropriately for smaller screens. Currently the image can scale down but it's too small for the smaller screens. First I tried using a media query then alternatively the picture tag. See below:

HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<picture>
<source srcset="logo3.jpg" media="(max-width: 480px)">
<source srcset="logo2.jpg">
<img class="logo" src="logo2.jpg" alt="name" width="220">
</picture>
```

OR

HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<img class="logo" src="logo2.jpg" alt="name" width="220">
```

CSS

```
.logo {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
width: 16%;
}

img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
.logo {
width: 150px;
}
```

I have been playing around with both the code and image sizes for a few hours now but nothing seems to work.

Is there something wrong with the code?

Please can someone provide me with a solution or point me in the right direction?

Ps. I am a beginner so please make it beginner-friendly :) thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a 'div' container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For images (or anything for that matter) your sizes cannot be in `px`, it has to be in `%`.

So if you want your image to scale, but not be allowed to be bigger than *x*, then you can do the following:

```
img{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 500px;
}
```

Now your image will always be 500px, but when your screen size becomes smaller than 500px, the image will take up 100% of the screen width.

This also eliminates the need to create media queries for everything.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have your styles inline for your logo.

```
<source srcset="logo3.jpg" media="(max-width: 480px)">
```

Would be much better off like this

```css
.logo3 {
  width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo3" src="logo3.jpg">
```

I would just have the logo in place once and size it differently based on the screen like this

```css
.logo3 {
  width: 220px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.logo3 {
  width: 480px;
}
}
```

```html
<img class="logo3" src="logo3.jpg">
```

Let me know if this is helpful.