# How to make logo (image) responsive in React Ant design layout?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant design layout in my React App.

I have added header and sidebar, I have some issue on the logo, when I click the toggle, after that the logo is not responsive. How do I make it responsive?

Here is [stazkblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qb4vh5?file=index.css).

**code**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd';
import {
  MenuUnfoldOutlined,
  MenuFoldOutlined,
  UserOutlined,
  VideoCameraOutlined,
  UploadOutlined,
} from '@ant-design/icons';

const { Header, Sider, Content } = Layout;

class SiderDemo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    collapsed: false,
  };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Sider trigger={null} collapsible collapsed={this.state.collapsed}>
          <div className="logo" />
          <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
            <Menu.Item key="1" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
              nav 1
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<VideoCameraOutlined />}>
              nav 2
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3" icon={<UploadOutlined />}>
              nav 3
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Sider>
        <Layout className="site-layout">
          <Header className="site-layout-background" style={{ padding: 0 }}>
            {React.createElement(this.state.collapsed ? MenuUnfoldOutlined : MenuFoldOutlined, {
              className: 'trigger',
              onClick: this.toggle,
            })}
          </Header>
          <Content
            className="site-layout-background"
            style={{
              margin: '24px 16px',
              padding: 24,
              minHeight: 280,
            }}
          >
            Content
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SiderDemo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a 'div' container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3029422/2873538)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `<div>` with background image (current implementation in the question) to show the logo.

And, use `<img>` with CSS to make it [responsive](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp).

**CSS:**

```
.logo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 169px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

**JSX:**

```
<img
  className="logo"
  src="https://www.skysens.io/images/white-logo.png"
/>
```