# CSS max-width and max-height results in a stretched image

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a lightbox where the current image takes up `90% of the height of the page` OR a `900px` width, whichever one happens first.

Naturally, I used the code below, expecting it to fail. I was right. I tried using the `aspect-ratio` property (which is frowned on because of its lack of browser support), but nothing worked.

Anybody know how to achieve this?

```
/* Basically the lightbox container */
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* Each image has the class mySlides */
.mySlides {
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 90%;
  margin: 15px 5%;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a 'div' container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container)

Comment: @PeterKrebs It would if I were willing to set fixed widths for my images. I'm trying to deal in percentages here so that each image always has a certain amount of space from the edge of the screen, not matter what device you're on. If all my images were 16/9 or something like that, my max-width:900px would work, but I have landscape AND portrait images that I'm trying to apply my code to. When I apply max-width to both a horizontal and portrait image, one or both of them will end up wrong. So I have to add in max-height to keep the portrait one from spilling offscreen, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what wrong with just those code. It work fine in my demo [link](https://jsfiddle.net/1x9ebzhw/)

Comment: Look into `object-fit: contain` ?

Comment: @HenryVarro I'm really confused as to why yours works and mine doesn't. I tried adding a pixel value to the max-height of the image (max-height: 200px) just as a test, and it didn't affect the image at all.

Comment: @AmauryHanser I just looked it up and messed around with it a bit. I think it might have worked but I'll do some more tests to confirm it. If it does, I'll post this as the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad that you could sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, a comment from Amaury Hanser got me on the right track. The solution that worked was using `object-fit: contain;`. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) helped me learn what that is. The property basically makes an object fit within the borders of its parent container while maintaining its aspect ratio.

This is my code now:

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.mySlides {
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 90%;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin: 15px 5%;
}
```