# Fit img in div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the best way to simulate upcoming CSS3 object-fit property using CSS2 & JS? I'm interested in contain & cover methods for fitting.

EDIT: In CSS3 there is the new object-fit mechanism described here: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-object-fit-object-position/ but object-fit is not yet supported outside the Opera browsers. To create a portable solution I need to make an `img` grow or shrink to the size of its parent `div` without loosing the original aspect ratio of the image. This can be achieved by either containing the whole image (technique also called letterboxing) or by enlarging & overflowing the image until the smallest dimension matches the `div`'s dimension (technique also called as cover). There are a few jquery imagefit libraries out there by they are very buggy (perhaps they work only in a specific situation on a specific browser).

EDIT 2: This question has been understood by those taking the time to read it, a good answer has been suggested and an answer has been given. It is difficult to understand the decision of closing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested, here's the actual working solution:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxjrV/6/)

and the actual code:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.imagefit = function(contain) {
    this.each( function() {
      var $this           = $(this),
          $wrapper        = $this.parent(),
          wrapper_width   = $wrapper.width(),
          wrapper_height  = $wrapper.height(),
          wrapper_ratio,
          image_ratio;


        // ratios
      image_ratio   = $this.width() / $this.height();
      wrapper_ratio = wrapper_width / wrapper_height;

      var ratio_cond = wrapper_ratio > image_ratio;
        if(contain) {
            ratio_cond = !ratio_cond;
        }

      if ( ratio_cond ) {
          $wrapper.css({
            'background'  : 'url('+$this.get(0).src+')',
            'background-size'  : '100% auto',
            'background-position'  : '0px 50%',
            'background-repeat'  : 'no-repeat'
          });
      } else {
          $wrapper.css({
            'background'  : 'url('+$this.get(0).src+')',
            'background-size'  : 'auto 100%',
            'background-position'  : '50% 0px',
            'background-repeat'  : 'no-repeat'
          });
      }

      $this.remove();

    });
    return this;
  };

  $('div.bgthumb#cover > img').imagefit(false);               
  $('div.bgthumb#contain > img').imagefit(true);               

}(jQuery));​
```

@Hippocrates: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You could also use `ratio_cond` to set a class on the wrapper element and then apply styles accordingly: `width: 100%; height: auto;` or the other way around and center it with something like `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`.

Comment: I used your solution and improved it a bit to answer a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30242945/2270233).

Answer (score 5):

Why use JavaScript or CSS3 stuff? just use this and you are good to go

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxjrV/)

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
}
/* This will resize you image according to the container size and 
   will retain the aspect ratio too */
```

Comment: Not sure why the down vote.. it's a decent solution imo. Only thing is that it will not go beyond the original size of the image

Comment: @dakdad ya but it's `Fit img in div container` else he can simply use `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Downvoting this because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @sqreept so what's your question?

Comment: What is the best way to simulate upcoming CSS3 object-fit property using CSS2 & JS? I'm interested in contain & cover methods for fitting.

Comment: but your question says this `Fit img in div container`, if you still need a full page background check this out, http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/, still it's not what you are looking for than sorry no1 understood your question probably...

Comment: If you have an answer to the question please write it down. If you're here to participate in a semantic dispute, I'm sorry, seats are sold out.

Comment: Am not here to dispute, if you think so am going mum...you can wait for your answer

Answer (score 2):

If you set the image as the background of the container you get a handy CSS property: background-size. 
Values can be seen here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Your answer seems to lead to the correct result: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxjrV/2/ which I'll post when JS is ready, too.

Comment: It really did get me to the right result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you need a cross-browser solution for stretchable background- maybe use some plugin like:
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way - without using background images. (note, I have not worried about positioning at this stage)

http://jsfiddle.net/Z5Hb8/2/

```
$('.resize').each(function(){
var el = $(this).find('img'),
    pael = el.parent(),
    ph = pael.height(),
    pw = pael.width(),
    pr = pw/ph,
    img = new Image();

img.src = el.attr('src');
img.onload = function() {
    var w = this.width,
        h = this.height,
        sr = w/h;

    if (pael.hasClass('cover')) {
        if (pr > sr) {
            el.width(pw);   
        } else {
            el.height(ph);
        }
    } else if (pael.hasClass('contain')) {
        if (sr > pr) {
           el.width(pw);
        } else {
           el.height(ph);
        }
    }        
}
});
```