# How can I fill a div with an image while keeping it proportional?

Tags: html, css, image

I found this thread — [How do you stretch an image to fill a <div> while keeping the image's aspect-ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891857/how-do-you-stretch-an-image-to-fill-a-div-while-keeping-the-images-aspect-rat) — that is not entirely the thing that I want.

I have a `div` with a certain size and an image inside of it. I want to **always** fill-out the `di`v with the image regardless if the image is landscape or portrait. And it doesn't matter if the image is cut-off (the div itself has overflow hidden).

So if the image is portrait I want the `width` to be `100%` and the `height:auto` so it stays in proportion. If the image is landscape I want the `height` to be `100%` and the `width to be` auto`. Sounds complicated right?

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="Could be portrait or landscape"/>
</div>
```

Since I don't know how to do it I simply created a quick image of what I mean. I can't even properly describe it.

[image]

So, I guess I'm not the first one asking this. However I couldn't really find a solution to this. Maybe there is some new CSS3 way of doing this - I'm thinking of flex-box. Any idea? Maybe it's even easier than I expect it to be?

Answer (score 248):

If I correctly understand what you want, you may leave the width and height attributes off the image to maintain aspect ratio and use `flexbox` to do the centering for you.

```css
.fill {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden
}
.fill img {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="fill">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/320/240" alt="" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx37G/1/).

I tested this successfully in IE9, Chrome 31, and Opera 18. But no other browsers were tested. As always you must consider your particular support requirements.

Comment: In IE9 the image is not centered vertically or horizontally with this method, it is aligned to the top and left. http://i59.tinypic.com/ouo77s.png

Comment: This has an issue on iPad, it appears safari stretches the image to 100% of its height but does not retain the min-width property.

Comment: This seems to scale small images up to fill, but not down to fit. At least when I use a large image it only shows a tiny portion of it.

Comment: To have a large image scaled down to fit, I used the following on the image: `.fill img { min-height:100%; min-width: 100%; object-fit: cover; } `

Comment: Thank you!!! I have been searching for this. Just needed these changes to `.fill img` change `flex-shrink` to `flex-shrink: 1` (or remove it) and add `object-fit: cover`. Basically change this css to what @PeterG said.

Answer (score 108):

It's a bit late but I just had the same problem and finally solved it with [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) with the help of another stackoverflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29103071).

```
img {
   object-fit: cover;
   width: 50px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Hope this still helps somebody.

Ps: Also works together with `max-height`, `max-width`, `min-width` and `min-height` css properties. It's espacially handy with using lenght units like `100%` or `100vh` or `100vw` to fill the container or the whole browser window.

Comment: is this a crossbrowser solution?

Comment: object-fit: cover; works great!
Browser info (does not work in IE):
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Fallback solution for IE:
https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3 MS is working on implementing it: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/objectfitandobjectposition/

Comment: I guess adding an `object-position` rule to this class will be helpful here. Just a side note.

Comment: Just add `width:100%; height :100%;`

Comment: This was the best option for my case, as I did not want to add any special classes, display flex, background-image etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

This should do it:

```css
img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Works pretty well for me, in my case I just required to add position:absolute and top:0 , and some z-index as well

Comment: very easy and clean solution without using fixed px for heights or width.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me resizing an image together with grid-row-start and grid-row-end

Answer (score 18):

All answers below have fixed `width` and `height`, which makes solution "not responsive".

To achieve the result but keep image responsive I used following:

1. Inside container place a transparent gif image with desired proportion
2. Give an image tag inline css background with image you want to resize and crop

```css
.container img{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img style="background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/XOmNCwY.jpg");" src="img/blank.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: I used background-image for my entire design portfolio company website so that I could have background-size: cover. Now my image SEO is all messed up because background images aren't recognized by Google. I wish I had coded it another way.

Comment: best of all answers for my case of *putting it into a cell in a grid layout*. It becomes distorted from stretching horizontally but not vertically as it places blank space for the avoiding of vertical stretch (made a change for the height `max-height: 100%;`), including `max-width:100%` kept the proportions as it was originally in the image but if the window changes it does not fill

Answer (score 12):

A simple way I figured out to do this is by using `object-fit: cover` on the img inside the container

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <img class="image" src="https://mymodernmet.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/International-Landscape-Photographer-Year-PhotographER-1st-KelvinYuen-2.jpg">
</div>
```

```css
.image { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover
}

.container {
  height: 100px; /*Set any dimensions you like*/
  width: 50px;
}
```

As far as I tested, this works regardless of the dimensions of the image to use, and this satisfies the "Best case" as you state in the question, since the result is vertically and horizontally centered.

Answer (score 8):

An old question but deserves an update as now there is a way.

The correct CSS based answer is to use `object-fit: cover`, which works like `background-size: cover`. Positioning would be taken care of by `object-position` attribute, which defaults to centering.

**But** there is no support for it in any IE / Edge browsers, or Android < 4.4.4. Also, `object-position` is not supported by Safari, iOS or OSX. Polyfills do exist, [object-fit-images](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/) seems to give best support.

For more details on how the property works, see [CSS Tricks article on `object-fit`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) for explanation and demo.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this using css flex properties. Please see the code below:

```css
.img-container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
.img-container .img-to-fit {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img class="img-to-fit" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/8633/nature-tree-green-pine.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: This works ONLY if you remove the width and height properties as alluded to in some of the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the CSS property [object-fit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_object-fit) on the img tag:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="some-image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) (IE9+) in conjunction with `background-image`. For IE8-, there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill).

Comment: Doesn't this require background-url?  Can you elaborate more?  Can this work with the <img src="" /> as stated in the question?

Comment: @harsimranb Of course, `background-size` makes sense solely with `background-image` specified too (I've updated my answer accordingly). It does not apply to `IMG` elements.

Comment: This is the best answer. It is simple and has good browser support. All other solutions are either very complex or not working in IE(9).

Answer (score 3):

```css
.image-wrapper{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.image-wrapper img {
    object-fit: contain;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="">
</div>
```

Comment: It seems in Chromium-based browsers `width: auto; height: auto` is not needed. This is the only answer that works in both dimensions and for both `object-fit: contain` and `object-fit: cover`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer with support to IE using `object-fit` so you won't lose ratio. Using a simple JS snippet to detect if the  `object-fit` is supported and then replace the `img` for a `svg`:

```js
//ES6 version
if ('objectFit' in document.documentElement.style === false) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('img[data-object-fit]').forEach(image => {
      (image.runtimeStyle || image.style).background = `url("${image.src}") no-repeat 50%/${image.currentStyle ? image.currentStyle['object-fit'] : image.getAttribute('data-object-fit')}`
      image.src = `data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='${image.width}' height='${image.height}'%3E%3C/svg%3E`
    })
  })
}

//ES5 version
if ('objectFit' in document.documentElement.style === false) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[data-object-fit]').forEach(function(image) {
      (image.runtimeStyle || image.style).background = "url(\"".concat(image.src, "\") no-repeat 50%/").concat(image.currentStyle ? image.currentStyle['object-fit'] : image.getAttribute('data-object-fit'));
      image.src = "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='".concat(image.width, "' height='").concat(image.height, "'%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }));
  });
}
```

```css
img {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red
}


/*for browsers which support object fit */

[data-object-fit='cover'] {
  object-fit: cover
}

[data-object-fit='contain'] {
  object-fit: contain
}
```

```html
<img data-object-fit='cover' src='//picsum.photos/1200/600' />
<img data-object-fit='contain' src='//picsum.photos/1200/600' />
<img src='//picsum.photos/1200/600' />
```

---

**Note:** There are also a few `object-fit` polyfills out there that will make `object-fit` work.

Here are a few examples:

- [object-fit-images](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images)
- [constancecchen /object-fit-pollyfill](https://github.com/constancecchen/object-fit-polyfill)
- [Polyfill for CSS object-fit property](https://github.com/tonipinel/object-fit-polyfill)

Answer (score 2):

My solution was:

```
<div
  style={{
    display: "flex",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  }}
>
  <img
    style={{
      minWidth: "100%",
      minHeight: "100%",
      objectFit: "cover",
    }}
    alt=""
    src={url}
  />
</div>
```

The above will scale up an image in order for it to **cover** the parent container.
If you just need to fit inside, then change `objectFit` to `contain`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
img {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use div to achieve this. without img tag :) hope this helps.

```css
.img{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-image:url('http://www.mandalas.com/mandala/htdocs/images/Lrg_image_Pages/Flowers/Large_Orange_Lotus_8.jpg');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center center;
 border:1px solid red;
 background-size:cover;
}
.img1{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-image:url('https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/9a4/large-pumpkin-1387927.jpg');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center center;
 border:1px solid red;
 background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="img"> 
</div>
<div class="img1"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting way I have learned to achieve this is by making **use of `padding-bottom` on the parent container to control the size and ratio of the image**.

When you use padding-bottom: 100% on an empty container, CSS automatically fills the width by 100%. With that, you can start playing around with the padding-bottom for the height and **optionally** adjust the width of the parent container to create the desired aspect ratio.

The parent element must be set as relative, and the image should be absolute, covering the entire container.

*Here's an example with a landscape and portrait image rendered in the same aspect ratio:*

```css
.container{
  padding-bottom: 40%;  
  position: relative;
width: 50%; //optional, use in combination with bottom padding as height
}

.container img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Using portrait image</h1>
<div class="container">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/14339714/pexels-photo-14339714.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" alt="Could be portrait or landscape"/>
</div>

<h1>Using landscape image</h1>
<div class="container">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/16208497/pexels-photo-16208497/free-photo-of-zee-natuur-wolken-kust.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" alt="Could be portrait or landscape"/>
</div>
```

*Best to run the snippet in full screen.*

source: https://v1.tailwindcss.com/course/locking-images-to-a-fixed-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0):

Here you have my working example. I have used a trick that is setting the image as background of the div container with background-size:cover and background-position:center center

I have placed the image with width:100% and opacity:0 making it invisible. Note that I am showing my image only because I have an special interest on calling the child click event.

Please note that altought I am ussing angular it is completely irrelevant.

```
<div class="foto-item" ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+foto.path+')'}">
    <img class="materialboxed" ng-class="foto.picid" ng-src="{{foto.path}}" style="opacity: 0;filter: alpha(opacity=0);" width="100%" onclick="$('.materialboxed')/>
 </div>
<style>
.foto-item {
height: 75% !important;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow:hidden;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
}
</style>
```

The result is the one that you define as optimal in all cases

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `object-fit: cover` and `object-position: left center` property values now address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Centering all. Even if the image width is greater than the container, showing the entire image. I can only do this using JS.**

*I know it's not the purpose of the post, but it was my purpose when I came here, and it may be useful to someone*!

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #000;
        }

        #container{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #my_img{
            height: 100%;
            width: auto;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <img src="images/filename.jpg" id="my_img">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        window.onload = function () {
            imgElem = document.getElementById('my_img');
            if (imgElem.width > document.body.scrollWidth) {
                // image is larger than container >> adjust by width and center
                imgElem.style.height = 'auto';
                imgElem.style.width = '100%';
                imgElem.style.position = 'relative';
                imgElem.style.transform = 'translateY(-50%)';
                imgElem.style.top = '50%';
            }
        }
        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Just fix the height of the image & provide width = auto

```
img{
    height: 95vh;
    width: auto;
}
```