# How to cover a div with an img tag (like background-image does)?

Tags: html, image, css

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142378/css-filling-a-div-with-an-image-while-staying-in-proportion) I am trying to get an image to be covered within a div. With just these simple lines I was able to achieve this via `background-image`:

```
div{
    width: 172px;
    height: 172px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-image: url('../images/img1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

In result the image was centered within the div and was resized so it would fit the width or the height of the div (depending if the image was wide or not).
Now I would like to achieve the same result with the image tag within the div.

```
<div>
  <img src="images/img1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Is there any way to get through this with plain CSS?

Comment: was there something wrong with this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20341542/1675954 - plain css, no js (why do you have the javascript tag?)

Comment: Yes, unfortunatelly. Images, that are bigger than the div appeared oversized...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39150019/1675954 object:cover; - another answer from the cited [same] question..

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use `object-fit:cover` to not lose ratio.

```css
div {
  border: black solid;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="//loremflickr.com/100/100" />
</div>
```

**NOTE:** this is [not supported in IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

---

It doesn't work in IE (by the way, it is an outdated browser, so please educate your clients to use at least the upgraded browser EDGE), but there are a few `object-fit` polyfills out there that will make `object-fit` work.

Here are a few examples:

- [object-fit-images](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images)
- [constancecchen /object-fit-pollyfill](https://github.com/constancecchen/object-fit-polyfill)
- [Polyfill for CSS object-fit property](https://github.com/tonipinel/object-fit-polyfill)

Or if you think its an overkill using a polyfill just for that property, here is simple snippet that will make this work in IE.

You can use a simple JS snippet to detect if the  `object-fit` is supported and then replace the `img` for a `svg`

```js
//for browsers which doesn't support object-fit (you can use babel to transpile to ES5)

if ('objectFit' in document.documentElement.style === false) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        document.querySelectorAll('img[data-object-fit]').forEach(image => {
            (image.runtimeStyle || image.style).background = `url("${image.src}") no-repeat 50%/${image.currentStyle ? image.currentStyle['object-fit'] : image.getAttribute('data-object-fit')}`
            image.src = `data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='${image.width}' height='${image.height}'%3E%3C/svg%3E`
        })
    })
}
```

```css
img {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

/*for browsers which support object fit */

[data-object-fit='cover'] {
  object-fit: cover
}

[data-object-fit='contain'] {
  object-fit: contain
}
```

```html
<img data-object-fit='cover' src='//picsum.photos/1200/600' />
<img data-object-fit='contain' src='//picsum.photos/1200/600' />
<img src='//picsum.photos/1200/600' />
```

Comment: I believe what the OP is requesting for is a background image of some sort where you can write over other elements on top of it.

Comment: Wow, worked for me! Thank you very much! I am working a little bit with drag and drop and try to swap images. That's why I switched from background image method to using img tags :)

Comment: object-fit: cover works great but the image is still not centered. It starts form the left top. how do you center the image with the object-fit method?

Comment: @Babulaas you probably dont want 'cover' but something else like 'fill'. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 8):

If you want to recreate the `background-size: cover;` look without using a CSS background image, you can use the following to achieve the desired result. Keep in mind, however, that there will always need to be a container holding the image.

```
div {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Depending on your additional CSS, you might want to use `max-width` and `max-height`.

Comment: depending on the use case you might need to add to img max-width: inherit

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
div {
    position:relative;
}
img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

This assumes you have given a size to the div.

Comment: This one wins because it is cross browser.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think this will stretch and distort the image away from it's native aspect ratio, unlike `background-size: cover`.

Comment: That is incorrect, height: 100%; and width: 100%; would distort the image. max-height and max-width maintains the aspect ratio. Give it a try :)

Comment: Sorry, but it stretches the image respectively shrinks it to a smaller size.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_image2  Change the css to img {max-height: 100%;max-width: 100%;} to see how it works, no stretching or distortion occurs

Comment: this is like background-size: contain and not cover

Comment: For me the perfect solution was using this answer combined with the object-fit: cover. Maybe had a different setup, but this was stretching the image for me.