# Why is flexbox container wider than the image it contains?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a simple webpage with a header and image below it. It needs to meet the following specifications:

- The sum of the header height and image height should total to the viewport height.
- The image should maintain its aspect ratio and should not be cropped.
- If the width of image is less than the viewport width, the image and header should be centered vertically.

[Here is an example of how I want it formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stwBP.jpg)

Below is my attempt to accomplish this:

```css
html,body,#root {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header-item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: blue;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
  <div class="top-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-item"></div>
        <div class="header-item"></div>
        <div class="header-item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="image" src="https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/lake-side-trees-live-desktop-jwhxpov3u0jdebb0.jpg"></img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/jimby/pen/poGOKBG)

This does everything I wanted except the `image-container` is wider than the image it contains. This prevents me from centering `container` correctly.

I suspect this is an issue with how flex containers calculate their width when they contain an image but I could be wrong. Any suggestions or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you setting the display to flex on pretty much every element?

Comment: Which elements don't justify `display: flex`? If you ask a more specific question I can try to talk through my reasoning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might reduce your code and have it working as desired.

As you can see, you don't really need all those containers and wrappers as they add more complexity but not more control over the layout. Having classnames on each element does not help either (contrary to popular BEM belief).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  header {
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-start;
    background-color: yellow;
  
    div {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: green;
      margin: 10px;
    }
  }
  
  img {
    display: block;
    max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </header>
  <img src="https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/lake-side-trees-live-desktop-jwhxpov3u0jdebb0.jpg">
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you this is a much more elegant solution. I have one follow up: how would we do this if we didn't know the size of `<header>` ahead of time or its height changed dynamically? I noticed you defined `max-height: calc(100% - 50px)` on `<img>` since `<header>` has a height of `50px`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `height: 100vh;` from the `html, body, #root` CSS ruleset in your example code seems to solve this issue.

```
html,body,#root {
  /* height: 100vh; */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Run this update and you will see the blue background is no longer visible on your image.

## SNIPPET:

```css
html,body,#root {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header-item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-item"></div>
        <div class="header-item"></div>
        <div class="header-item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="image" src="https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/lake-side-trees-live-desktop-jwhxpov3u0jdebb0.jpg"></img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

## Further details:

The cause is `justify-content: flex-start;` which is aligning the image to the start of the container (left hand side) so if you set this to  `justify-content: center;` the blue bordering will be visible on both sides.

The container box size still exceeds the image size because you're giving the image it's maximum width (but no default width) and a maximum height but the size ratio of the container is different from the image. You should probably look into some sort of `cover`/overflow aspect [such as in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091567/how-to-cover-a-div-with-an-img-tag-like-background-image-does):

```
.image {
   width:100%; /*change this to remove max- */
   object-fit:cover; /* Add this */
}
```

## Snippet 2:

retaining the `#root` rules:

```css
html,body,#root {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header-item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-item"></div>
        <div class="header-item"></div>
        <div class="header-item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="image" src="https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/lake-side-trees-live-desktop-jwhxpov3u0jdebb0.jpg"></img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly address what I was asking. Removing `height: 100vh;` from `html, body, #root` changes the height of `image` and `image-container`. This means I no longer satisfy the height requirement I listed in the first bullet.

Comment: Furthermore, the all the other solutions you proposed don't accomplish what I was looking for. Changing `justify-content: start` to `justify-content: center;` changes how the image is centered relative to the header. Changing to `object-fit:cover` will crop the image as you can see in your code snippet. Removing `max-width` and `max-height` and replacing it with `width: 100%` will not preserve aspect ratio when the window is sufficiently wide.

Answer (score -1):

To do that, I'll first grab the content container, that's the one that wraps around everything and set its display to flex. This creates a flexible box that flexes based on the intrinsic size of its elements. And as a result we get horizontal scrolling because these images are huge.

Comment: You should copy the snippet down here and demonstrate your solution. See [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).