# Image height same as width

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an image inside of a container and I want it to be a perfect square. I'm setting my width to be 100% of the container and the goal is to get the `height` of the image to be the same as the width, as I don't know what size the container will be due to responsive design.

Any ideas? I'm using sass, if that helps..

```css
.container {
width: 50%;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px; //this should be the same as the width value..
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1249588/pexels-photo-1249588.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"/></div>
```

Preferably no javascript solution, but maybe it's not possible otherwise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Height equal to dynamic width (CSS fluid layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout)

Comment: i think there is no pure css solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css height same as width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537806/css-height-same-as-width)

Comment: Set padding to 100%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Comment: @mr.void There is a css solution. Sell all posted links.

Comment: I don't see an indication of whether you want the image to keep its aspect ratio or not...

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, it should keep aspect ratio.. i guess the container should be a perfect square and the image should either be a square or centered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS force image resize and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio); Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23675095), since it's been updated for modern browsers.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think that the author needs to fit an image (any aspect ratio) in a responsive square. As you can see, in his exemple, the image isn't a square.

Comment: This is likely closer then: [How can I fill a div with an image while keeping it proportional?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14142378)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Updated answer (05/11/2023):

CSS is an always evolving language and we can now use `aspect-ratio`.

This solution requires less code and is less hacky, that's what I would use today.

> **aspect-ratio:**
> The aspect-ratio CSS property sets a preferred aspect ratio for the box, which will be used in the calculation of auto sizes and some other layout functions.

[aspect-ratio on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio)
[CSS property: aspect-ratio on caniuse](https://CSS%20property:%20aspect-ratio)

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;  /* defining the aspect ratio of the image */
  object-fit: cover;    /* making sure the image isn't distorted */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1249588/pexels-photo-1249588.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" />
</div>
```

---

### Original answer:

Many of us had given you **some hints in the comments**, so by now you should be able to create a **responsive square**.

Fit the image inside the square
**Just in case you are missing the last part**, here is how you can **fit the image** (with any aspect ratio) **into that square**. It also means that your image will be cropped if it's not squared.

Snippet:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 37%; /* The size you want */
}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* The padding depends on the width, not on the height, so with a padding-bottom of 100% you will get a square */
}

.container img {
  position: absolute; /* Take your picture out of the flow */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; /* Make the picture taking the size of it's parent */
  width: 100%; /* This if for the object-fit */
  height: 100%; /* This if for the object-fit */
  object-fit: cover; /* Equivalent of the background-size: cover; of a background-image */
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1249588/pexels-photo-1249588.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"/>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is truly a duplicate, you probably shouldn't be answering it...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I know, but I couldn't find an asnwer for an image inside the square. All the answers I've read were only talking about the creation of the square. If I find one with the image, I'll delete the answer

Comment: @AmauryHanser: It is wonderfull! I save alot of time! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AmauryHanser thanks a lot this this solution, helped me a lot

Comment: this actually solved my problem. don't delete this post.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the top of your styling file:

```
    :root{
  --size: 100px;
}
```

Then give the defined variable to both width and height:

```
width: var(--size);
height: var(--size);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use a background image then this solution will work https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpyrwB .

This will keep a square ratio and make the image cover the whole div. It will also keep the image centered and crop the sides if the image is wider than the height.

**HTML**

```
<div class='square-box'>
    <div class='square-content'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.square-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.square-box:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.square-content{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1249588/pexels-photo-1249588.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another trick could be to use the image itself into its own background, then apply the vertical padding method with an height of 0.

demo below (with a dummyimage, yours doesn't show for me)

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;/* padding will mage sizing here */
  padding: 50% 0;/* make it a square = 100% vertical padding , none horizontal*/
  background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/750x1260/951&text=My_BG_Image);/* used a different color from the one in the tag */
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /* reset just in case */
  background-clip: border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/750x1260/159&text=My_Image" /></div>
```

Note, i also used the size of your image which is also not a square. Did you mind about stretching too ?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an allround solution for bootstrap 5. Here is a bootstrap 5 solution for a 100% width perfect circle image:

**HTML**

```
<div class="imageContainer position-relative w-100 rounded-circle overflow-hidden">
   <img class="position-absolute top-0 start-0 w-100 h-100" src="https://placekitten.com/100/200" loading="lazy"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imageContainer {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.imageContainer img{
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this works for you?

```
.container img {
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This only works with a tag that has background color or background image, not works with <img> tag