# How to create a sticky background using css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a sticky background using CSS,
something like this (the pink background will be completely filled but for example sake I kept a minimum  visible height)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}

#rest {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;

}

#content {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
#sticky_back
{
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background-color: pink;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="rest">
      <div id="sticky_back"></div>
      <div id="content">
        <span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
      </div>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but I can't seem to overlap the 2 pink and yellow `div`s
If I try to change the `position:absolute` and `relative` then the text in the `content` overflows like this

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;

}

#rest {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
    position: relative;
}

#content {
min-height:100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,0%);
  top:0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#sticky_back
{
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background-color: pink;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="rest">
      <div id="sticky_back"></div>
      <div id="content">
        <span>
           psum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor st dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu f
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I can create the desired background while avoiding overflow?

**EDIT**
If you were looking for a completely background filling solution then check this link:
[How to fit a sticky background image and prevent overflow in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66398033/how-to-fit-a-sticky-background-image-and-prevent-overflow-in-css/66543529#66543529)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `height` of `#sticky_back` is unknown, you can use a `grid` layout.

Add `display: grid` to the parent (`#rest`), and add `grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2` to both children (`#content` and `#stick_back`).

You will also need to add `z-index: 0` to `#content` to bring the element to the front.

```css
#rest {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  .
  .
  .
   
 #content {
  z-index: 0;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  .
  .
  .
  
 #sticky_back {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;  
  .
  .
  .
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;  
}

#rest {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  background: blue;
}

#content {
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 0;  
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}

#sticky_back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;  
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="rest">
    <div id="sticky_back"></div>
    <div id="content">
      <span>
        psum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor st dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu f
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: and if the height is unknown?

Comment: @lemonface, I have adjusted my initial answer to work when the `height` of the pink background (`#sticky_back`) is unknown. Check it out...

Comment: thank you it works!
but will it work if I replace the pink bar with a background image?
something like this https://jsfiddle.net/w4j1e68L/3/
but the image is the "best case" in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142378/how-can-i-fill-a-div-with-an-image-while-keeping-it-proportional

Comment: @lemonface, it will work if the pink bar is a background image: https://codepen.io/gcwebdev/pen/gOLeNNe. Make sure your `img` selector does not have a `#` in front of it. It should be `#sticky_back img` NOT `#img`.