# How do you make a div that covers the whole top part of the screen? and how do you insert an image that will fill in that entire div?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently doing a practice but I can't seem to get it to work.

i'd give some code but idk how to indent the code so for this use this jpg.

https://roco.studio/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/img_banner-thin_mountains.jpg

Comment: Your Question is not clear, hard to understand what you exactly need. so please give more details. then only you will get proper solution for your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fill a div with an image while keeping it proportional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142378/how-can-i-fill-a-div-with-an-image-while-keeping-it-proportional)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img-wrapper{
width:100%;}
.img-wrapper img{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://roco.studio/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/img_banner-thin_mountains.jpg" />
</div>
```