# How can I implement alternative text on an element with a background image?

Tags: html, alt-attribute

AIOSEO site health states this image has no alt text tag. How do I fix it and save the change so it solves the issue? Thanks

```
<div class="_9VmET" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://snw.202.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/cropped-Monstro-Video-Camera-8K-150x150.png&quot;);"></div>
```

Tried adding `alt="camera"` to div class but change doesn't save after adding change. What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: `alt` is an _attribute_, not a tag. Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the tour so you know how to use this site.

Comment: If it's an image that conveys information not already duplicated in the text then it shouldn't be a background image (but `alt="camera"` is very unlikely to be [*good* alt text](https://jkorpela.fi/html/alt.html)). If it is a decorative background image then it shouldn't need alt text.

Comment: are you sure you are not using that image in another place as an `img` tag?

Comment: The right solution depends on context. You might revise to add more markup so we can see how this element is presented.

Answer (score 1):

Divs don't have `alt` attributes. If the goal is to make this element accessible for the visually impaired, you have a number of options.

- Put some text nearby describing the background image.
- Use ARIA roles and labels. See https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/ARIATechnique_usingImgRole_with_aria-label_forCSS-backgroundImage.
- Put some text *inside* that element, in say a span element, and hide it with CSS so only screen readers see it. See https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent.

You could also implement an actual image element with an `alt` attribute and set sizing to cover the div completely so that the layout outcome is the same. See [How can I fill a div with an image while keeping it proportional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142378/how-can-i-fill-a-div-with-an-image-while-keeping-it-proportional).