# Fit image to screen using CSS with Slick Carousel

Tags: html, css, slick

I am making an image carousel using Slick. I want to fit the width of the image along screen and the height is scaled with the width. Below is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>slick test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    
        <div class="carousel-container">
            <div >
                <img class="carousel" src="images/1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div >
                <img class="carousel" src="images/2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div >
                <img class="carousel" src="images/3.jpg">
            </div>
    
        </div>

    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my attempt in `style.css`:

```
.carousel-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The images seem to be printed at its original resolution.

How to make it right? Do I need to change anything in `slick.css` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand this line

> the height is scaled with the width

Hope this is what you want.

```css
.carousel-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
}
.img-carousel{
  width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover
}
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>slick test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    
        <div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="carousel" >
                <img class="img-carousel" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel">
                <img class="img-carousel" src="https://picsum.photos/100/300">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel">
                <img class="img-carousel" src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
            </div>
    
        </div>

    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('.carousel-container').slick({
        arrows:false            
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

here to make the image fill entire scree I have made div to 100wv then added [`width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75020405/11139453) to the img tag.

added few settings to slick

```
<script>
  $('.carousel-container').slick({
    arrows:false,
  });
</script>
```

`arrows:false,` to hide arrows.

Comment: That solved my problem! Thanks a lot! About "the height is scaled with the width", I mean to make it maintain the aspect ratio. Could you explain the change you made? I am new to HTML and CSS.

Comment: instead of applying width 100vw directly to the image I have added it to div and i have made image to cover the entire screen of its parent (i.e div with 100vw). additionally we will have default 5 px padding or margin to the body, I have removed it removed it.

for more object-fit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit