# Stretch width of div background image with set height

Tags: html, css, background, width, stretch

I am trying to stetch a div background image but **not** keep the aspect ratio. So I want a fixed height of 270px and a width 100% of the screen. It works perfectly in chrome but not in IE or Firefox. Here is what I have now:

CSS:

```
#container {
background-image: url(images/blur.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 270px;
width:100%;
height:270px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">content</div>
```

I'm a little new to all this so sorry if I am asking a really simple question!

*Update: It's all working now. I'm really not sure what happened. I checked this over and over but closing everything and then opening my source code showed that it had changed the css from background size: 100% 270px; to just 100%. Absolutely bizarre! Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: cover;`? That's a good one, but it does maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you stretch an image to fill a <div> while keeping the image's aspect-ratio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891857/how-do-you-stretch-an-image-to-fill-a-div-while-keeping-the-images-aspect-rat)

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me in Firefox 22 and IE 10:
http://jsfiddle.net/FFMSV/ Any particular version not working?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. It seems it was a bug with notepad of all things!

Comment: I highly doubt there was a bug with notepad. More likely, you needed to clear your browser cache.

Comment: I would think that too except it changed the code in Notepad not the browser. I originally had the background set to just 100% but changed it later. And I know it was correct, I checked it over and over. On closing and re-opening Notepad it reverted to saying just 100%. Added the 240px and it was working fine. I never would have suspected Notepad either thus why I was so stumped!

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you need to include the

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

element