# How to increase width of image when dimensions are not known in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image tag like

```
<img />
```

I then dynamically download a link to an image, and I set the image src to that link. I do not know the dimensions of the image in the link. Is there a CSS code I can use to make sure the width of the image is exactly 200px (no crop, just stretch to fit) and the height of the image is the same as on the original image? (so basically just a horizontal scale when original dimensions are not known). Whatever I try, it seems to preserve the aspect ratio.

Thanks

Here's an example: I am dynamically loading this image:
[image]

I don't know its dimensions, But in the end, I want it to look like (pretend its width is 200px).

[image]

Comment: why don't you use `style` ?. Thus `<img src="" style="width:200px;">`

Comment: That preserves aspect ratio.

Comment: No, it should stretch to fit. Have it stretch to fit horizontally, and keep vertical height same as on original image.

Comment: Where do I specify 200px then?

Comment: you mean for smaller images <200px it is preserving aspect ratio?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101907/discussion-between-pratikwebdev-and-omega).

Comment: No, for any image. It should make the width 200px (either stretching stretching or compressing depending if original size is less or more than 200px).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you stretch an image to fill a <div> while keeping the image's aspect-ratio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891857/how-do-you-stretch-an-image-to-fill-a-div-while-keeping-the-images-aspect-rat)

Comment: That is to preserve aspect ratio. In my case I do **not** want it to preserve aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

```
function formatImage(t)
{
    //var t = document.getElementById("idOfImg");
    alert(t.naturalWidth + " " + t.naturalHeight);
    t.height = t.naturalHeight;
    t.width = "200";

}
```

On every `image` that you want this behavior add `onload=formatImage(this);`

**JSFiddle**
    https://jsfiddle.net/94rzcLh6/

Lmk if it works. I have not used proper naming on fiddle kindly ignore that.

Comment: the question is without .js

Comment: ah my bad. if OP feels like referring it :) but your solution works well too. Since OP mentioned earlier it will be for number of images in that case it might be useful and simple to keep existing html code with minimal changes.

Comment: @pratikwebdev I agree with your answer, but I wonder why the OP did only specify CSS to begin with

Comment: @AGE Agreed! May be OP did not use JS in existing code hence it might have not crossed OPs mind. I just suggested this solution on broader basis considering multiple elements and related work efforts for coding.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

css:

```
.content{
  display:table;
}

.thumb{
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.thumb .in, .thumb .in img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="in">
      <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/cache/7b/30/7b306aff620b08d0eefdb6b37f57abc8.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="in">
      <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/cache/a6/4f/a64ffdfc06a8bea4ed2e62f2a44b063d.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="in">
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.es/gi-resources/images/RoyaltyFree/113198687.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/406nnjpj/)

In the jsfidle sample I check the height and this preserve it.Taking from 2 browsers.The same is for other images.

[image]

Comment: This seems to preserve aspect ratio, which is not what I want. I want the height to remain the same as original image height.

Comment: you want the height is the same for all images?

Comment: I put an example image in my original post.

Comment: Yes, same as original image height.

Comment: @omega check again. is thus?

Comment: the jsfiddle still seems to preserve aspect ratio, and doesn't look like my example above.

Comment: I set the image to 200px with the original height. @omega what's wrong?

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying the current fiddle code you have is currently working? Because when I check, it looks like its not working. I.e. the aspect ratio is preserved when it should not be.

Comment: I still see same results in fiddle? I am confused now.

Comment: In chrome it does the trick.
But in Firefox the image is scaled down

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your image in a container that can help you preserve the `200px` constrain you want to apply on your image. The height will adapt to the width which is neat since you won`t have to worry about it.

The below example shows what you can do with a custom size image, from **[placeholdit](http://placehold.it/)**, you can modify it as you like. I also advise you to play around with the `.wrapper` width in order to identify any changes you wish to apply such as adding `width: 200px; width: auto;` instead... this `.wrapper` is a very flexible container and that is what you need, you can change it however you like.

**EDIT**

Going by the comments below, I decided to modify the wrapper of the image to force the image to lose it's aspect ratio. First, I am using a `position: absolute` (you can also use `position: fixed`). I also made the image dimensions completely disproportionate to the `.wrapper` dimensions, to further elaborate on the necessity of losing aspect ratio.

Note: Since it is only a demonstration, I am not worrying about multiple images and how to position them properly (that is another question entirely).

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100%; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
}

.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1500x1000" alt="some image">
</div>
```

Feel free to play around with the `.wrapper` to

Comment: I'm not sure this is working. Can you change the placeholder image to 400 width and 200 height, and see if it works?

Comment: It seems to also preserve aspect ratio

Comment: I put an example image in my original post.

Comment: @omega sorry for the delay, in the middle of work right now. Working on editing my post right now

Comment: @omega I have modified my answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: In the snippet, the height of the image looks like 200px, but it should be 1000px..... This suggests its preserving aspect ratio when it should not be.

Comment: @omega that is because the height is set to 100px, you can change that to whatever you like within the wrapper class

Comment: The thing is the height should be dynamic, it needs to be what the original image height is. So I can't hardcode the exact height in the css.

Comment: @omega Height 100% is dynamic l, have you tried using your own images to identify whether or not this is true for you?

Comment: @miglio I haven't actually taken a look at it, give me a couple of minutes

Comment: @miglio honestly the OP is stating that the JSFiddles are preserving aspect ratio when they clearly are not, therefore the OP is in need of something that they are not clearly specifying. I suppose it would have been **much** easier to do a JavaScript implementation, however the tags in the question did not specify this either, yet the OP accepted a JavaScript solution. Go figure