# Have an image fill all the div (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have on my website divs whose width varies with the width of the window, and I'd like to have a background for these divs. When I'm in full screen (1920*1080), the background images are exactly how I want them to be :
[image: it's ok here]
But when I resize my window, I get this :
[image: not ok]
I used the `background-size:cover;` attribute but it does not seem to work...

CSS :

```
.cleft1 {
    width: 33.333333%;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0;
    background-image: url('../img/aero.png');
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: `background-size:cover` doesn't seem to work ? Can you work out a snippet reproducing your problem ? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yup, here you go : `.cleft1 {
    width:33.333333%;
    height:300px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:0;
    background-image:url('../img/aero.png');
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891857/how-do-you-stretch-an-image-to-fill-a-div-while-keeping-the-images-aspect-rat

Comment: background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: @narfi Please  have a look at the "snippet" button in the toolbar when editing your question

Comment: Show us your code in the post please. All of the code needed to reproduce this part of the page as a [mcve] in the post itself - not just the CSS.

Comment: @Steveo : it works ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @narfi No problem!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this. I am not sure if it will work. didn't tested it yet.

```
   .your-div { 
      background: url(img.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```