# Bootstrap carousel, with cover images and indicators

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I need a (responsive) bootstrap carousel - much like the standard example:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

However, I need each images to 'cover' the containing div. So if it's a different ratio to the image the top & bottom, or left & right will be not visible - avoiding black bars.

I also need the left & right navigation buttons present, as well as the dot indicators allowing navigation & for users to see which image they are on.

I also need text within each slide that changes with each slide / isn't static. I found this but it has static text - I was unable to get the text moving - it also lacks the navigation buttons and dot indicators:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fullscreen-background-carousel

How can I do this? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with using background images, you could use the CSS property `background-size: cover` to make the background image cover the entire carousel slide div. Then your text would also be inside the slide div and sit on top of the background image. [You can read more about background-size here.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

[Here is a Fiddle demonstrating the use of background images with `background-size: cover`.](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlerjason/wxvauq9a/14/)

If you need the images to load in `img` tags, then you could use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891857/how-do-you-stretch-an-image-to-fill-a-div-while-keeping-the-images-aspect-rat) that uses JavaScript to determine if the image is wide or tall, and then applies the appropriate CSS styling.

Comment: Thanks - would it be possible to add a code example implementing what you're suggesting, I'm unclear on exactly how to do it? I have no strong views on using background images or not.

Comment: @nicco - I added a Fiddle link to my answer. I think using a background image is fine. Just know that the height of your slides (which have the class `.item`) should be set with CSS if you want them all to be the same height.