# making transition effect width 100% to cover page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I downloaded this transistion effect from [Transistion effect page](https://tympanus.net/Development/ImageTransitions/index3.html)

[source download page](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/19/experimental-css3-animations-for-image-transitions/comment-page-1/#comments)
I want to do this transistion effect with image being of 100% width filling the full page

can this transition be modified easily to cover the full page width.
I have modified the divs classes to 100% and set image style 100% css but what happens is it becomes small does the transition and enlarges again. Please advise the best solution to enable this transition to apply with 100% width.

Thanks

Comment: @YoungKyunJin You don't have to shout at him.

Comment: added sorce download link

Comment: @Jer I'm sorry. I don't used to english and I don't know english rule. I don't want to be rude. I'm sorry.

Comment: make note i am paticularly interested in multi-flip3 transition which i want to be able to implement as full page

Comment: The answer is available in stackoverflow itself. Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891857/how-do-you-stretch-an-image-to-fill-a-div-while-keeping-the-images-aspect-rat