# Bootstrap - 2 columns of matching height, 1 with full width image, 1 with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a difficulty getting something to work in Bootstrap 3.3.7. Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/rrqt9e98/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: red;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x333">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: yellow;">
      <p>
      Content column
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output is currently like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is get my image (which has an original size of 500*333px) to occupy the full width of the left hand column. I've set `width: 100%` in my CSS on the `img` to achieve this, following advice given here: [How do you stretch an image to fill a <div> while keeping the image's aspect-ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891857/how-do-you-stretch-an-image-to-fill-a-div-while-keeping-the-images-aspect-rat)

I'm not sure why the red background colour behind the image appears, as I want the image flush with the `col-md-6` edges. So I tried adding:

```
img {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

I also would like the right hand yellow column to match the height of the image. I am using the jQuery Match height plugin in my project, so could opt for that, unless there is a CSS solution.

The overall effect I would like is a 2 column layout where the image takes up the full left hand column, and that the right hand column matches the height of the left hand column. At a mobile breakpoint (`sm` or lower) I would like to horizontally stack these 2 columns.

I want it to look like this (which I've mocked up in Fireworks just to show how it should look):

[image]

Please can someone point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: Columns in Bootstrap have gutters, in the form of left and right padding, which is why you see the red background: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1615 - you can test this by removing the padding, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/rrqt9e98/2/

Comment: I've added a screenshot of how I'd like it to look

Comment: Unless you want to upgrade to Bootstrap 4, the simplest solution is to move your background color to the row: https://jsfiddle.net/rrqt9e98/3/

Comment: @TiesonT. I can't upgrade to Bootstrap 4 due to the rest of the project working in Bootstrap 3. The link looks good though so if you want to post that as a solution I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns in Bootstrap have gutters, in the form of left and right padding, which is why you see the red background: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1615 - you can test this by removing the padding, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/rrqt9e98/2

Rather than trying to get the right column to stretch to fill the same height as the left column, just apply your color to the row instead:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background-color: yellow;">

    <div class="col-md-6 no-gutter" style="background-color: red;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x333">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 no-gutter">
      <p class="p1">
      Content column
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with the relevant CSS:

```
.no-gutter
{
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.p1
{
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Fiddle, with some padding added to the paragraph in the right column: https://jsfiddle.net/rrqt9e98/5/

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6 nopadding" style="background-color: red; width:500px">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x333">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 nopadding" style="background-color: yellow; height:333px">
        <p>
        Content column
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Even with `.container-fluid` it's still not right, the red background remains. I've updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rrqt9e98/1/. Also, I don't want that content to take up the full width of the view port, I need it contained within `.container` to centre align it in the viewport. I don't want to have this inside `.container-fluid`.

Comment: So what you need is the red area should not be visible, right?

Comment: Yes, the red area should not be visible because the image should occupy the full width of the left hand `.col-md-6`.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of how I'd like it to look

Comment: I updated my reply, it might not be the best way to do it but at least its like on your SS