# Picture not aligning in my DIV

Tags: html, css

Not sure what's going on here. I re-seized the image to match the width of the div but somehow it still doesn't align with it. I uploaded the issue to codepen here. Tried to play around with the margins but its still doesn't change the behavior.

```
.propertyOverview.mapView {
  height: 430px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.propertyImage.mapViewPic {
  height: 260px;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.quickDetails {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.propertyOverview p {
  margin: 0px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .7px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #272635;
}

.propertyOverview .priceDetail {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #272635;
}

.quickFacts {
  border-top: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  color: #272635;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/insivika/pen/PEzxPK

Comment: need `html` and ur pen is not a full link

Comment: Please check the codepen url you posted.

Comment: here it is again, please let me know if you still can't pull it up

Comment: https://codepen.io/insivika/pen/PEzxPK

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't align with it"? Do you want the image width and height stretched to fill the container or do you want it to be centred within?

Comment: exactly! The width of the picture should be the width of the div

Comment: @insivika, you can use `min-width: 100%;` on the image. Alternatively, you can use the `background-image` property of the div. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891857/how-do-you-stretch-an-image-to-fill-a-div-while-keeping-the-images-aspect-rat) might help you as well.

Comment: Let me take a look min-width didn't adjust the width...

Comment: .propertyImage.mapViewPic {
   height: 260px;
   min-width: 100% !important;
   border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
   text-align : center;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, I guess you are trying to stretch the image to take up whole width of container. Here is the problem:

```
<div class="propertyImage mapViewPic">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ivV9vR/sample_Property_Map1.png" 
     alt="sample_Property_Map1" alt="">
</div>

.propertyImage.mapViewPic {
    height: 260px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

You have given a class to parent container of the image and targeting it in CSS.

Instead do this. Remove the extra container `div`

```
<div class="propertyOverview mapView">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ivV9vR/sample_Property_Map1.png" 
     alt="sample_Property_Map1" alt="" class="propertyImage">
</div>
```

Update your CSS like this.

```
.propertyOverview .mapViewPic {
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: are you positive I applied what you're showing me but it didn't do the trick. I really appreciate your help

Comment: I see you remove the .mapViewPic class from the div but how are you then still trying to to style it...?

Comment: Ha! it should be .propertyImage .mapViewPic {
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

Comment: I removed the extra div and at the same time copied its class to the img.

Then the target element in CSS should be .propertyOverview .mapViewPic

Answer (score 1):

Issue is @

```
.propertyOverview.mapView {
    height: 430px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Where width is 600px and the image width is 360px. Thats why the extra space.

```css
.propertyOverview.mapView {
    height: 430px;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 50px;
}


.propertyImage.mapViewPic {
   height: 260px;
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.quickDetails {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.propertyOverview p {
    margin: 0px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: .7px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #272635;
}

.propertyOverview .priceDetail {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
     color: #272635;
}


.quickFacts {
    border-top: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    color: #272635;
    font-size: 15px;
}


.quickFact1,  
.quickFact2,
.quickFact3,
.like {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.like {
    margin-left: 110px;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #cccccc;
    
}

.like:hover,
.like:active {
    color: #FF3366;
}
```

```html
 <div class="propertyOverview mapView">
     <div class="propertyImage mapViewPic">
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ivV9vR/sample_Property_Map1.png" alt="sample_Property_Map1" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="quickDetails">
     <p>5689 Main Ave</p>
     <p>Los Angeles, CA 90019</p>
     <p class="priceDetail">$556,000</p>
     </div>
     <div class="quickFacts">
      <div class="quickFact1">2 br</div>   
      <div class="quickFact2">2 bth</div>   
      <div class="quickFact3">4,000 SF</div> 
      <div class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></div> 
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aligning an image is same as aligning a text....
If you want your image to be centrally aligned with any div tag as you mentioned then their may be two possibilities that either align it relative to the div tag or you align both div and image together

If you want both div and image to be centrally aligned 
use

```
.propertyImage.mapViewPic {
text-align : center;
height: 260px;
width: 600px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
div{
text-align: center;
}
```

This will align both of your div and image centrally taking into note that the image is not a child element of the div tag you mentioned, otherwise the image will be aligned with relative to the the div tag

Comment: Ok cool this does align the pic in the center however the width is for some reason not applied..

Answer (score 0):

[You can check this link](https://jsfiddle.net/cok20nff/)

```
.propertyImage.mapViewPic {  
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center; 
}
```

**You can also set text-align: center; for img tag**

**if you want full image of div **

```
.propertyImage.mapViewPic {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.propertyImage.mapViewPic img {
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you but it needs to be the whole width of the div

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login page</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
    .mm {
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mm"> <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/1250833953592952166.png"/> </div>
</body>
</html>
```