# Scale Html Image to Fit Width inside TextView

Tags: android, html, image, android-layout, textview

I have a TextView with HTML content inside it. The HTML code contains img tags which are loaded using Html.ImageGetter. The images are displayed fine, but I wan't to make them scale so that the image width spans the entire width of the TextView. This width (and the scaling) should change when the phone is rotated. So basically, I would like to have the same effect as using css rule "width: 100%".

Is this even possible to do using TextViews?

Comment: Did you check [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11768235/1396082)

Comment: Why don't you use WebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767916/scaling-images-in-html-with-a-minimum-width-height-in-html-css-only/11768235#11768235) that as posted to comments, link only answers are not good...

Don't use an . Instead, use a background-image style:

```
background: transparent url('path/to/image.png') no-repeat scroll center center; 
background-size: contain;
```

The background-size does the magic, scaling the image up or down so that it snugly fits inside the container.