# Proportionally resize an image with just HTML and using a input tag?

Tags: html, image, input, resize

```
<form name="loginform" action="URL_TO_LOGIN_PAGE_GOES_HERE" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="log" value="USERNAME" />
<input type="hidden" name="pwd" value="PASSWORD" />
<input type="submit" value="" class="mtrgimg" style="background:url(http://aff.securesb.info/accounts/default1/banners/b40a4792.png) center no-repeat; width:145px; height:145px; border:none; cursor:pointer;" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kr3n4/1/

I would like for the image in this button to be proportionally resized to 145x145. I do not have access to the stylesheet so I cannot use any CSS. Also, cannot use JavaScript. There must be a way to resize using just HTML.

Also, when it is all said and done, I would also like this button to open its link in a new new tab or window.

Comment: Impossible without CSS or JS.

Comment: @Babblo No kidding? Ok. Thanks. I will just pre-size the image using Photoshop and then upload it to the FTP and replace my current URL with the new one. Just wanted to know if it was possible. Also, what about opening up the "submit action" in a new tab?

Comment: You could try with target"_blank" in the form but I'm not sure if that still work. BTW, why you can't use css or js ?

Comment: @Babblo because it is a massive software that i am working with and the CSS is protected via alpha and beta and it would be a huge project to change the CSS - QA would need to get involved.. and our true development team.. Anyway, it's all good. We figured it all out thanks to you guys on S.O.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like for the image in this button to be proportionally resized
>   to 145x145. I do not have access to the stylesheet so I cannot use any
>   CSS. Also, cannot use JavaScript. There must be a way to resize using
>   just HTML.

Well, your `style` tag in the `<input>` is (inline) CSS. You can use that and follow the methods [discussed in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787839/resize-image-proportionally-with-css?rq=1), for example.

> Also, when it is all said and done, I would also like this button to open its link in a new new tab or window.

You can put `target="_blank"` on the `<form>` tag to open the page set as the `action` in a new window.

Comment: Thanks boss. The target="_blank" did it! And I just manually resized the images with Photoshop and then referenced the new URLs. All done!