# Can't resize image using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I've tried every answer I could find on all the sites I could find, but still haven't been able to properly resize an image using CSS. I've got it inside a div, and tried resizing either one and resizing both. I'm trying to fit the image (underneath my navigation bar) to the page (meaning: as wide as the page, and relative height).

```
<div id="banner"><img src="resources/img/banner.png" class="myImage"></div>
```

First attempt:

```
.myImage{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Second attempt:

```
#banner{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Third attempt:

```
<div id="banner"><img src="resources/img/banner.png" id="myImage"></div>

#banner{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#myImage{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong with your attempts? Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Have you considered `width:100%`? You seem to have only tried `max-width`.

Comment: can you publish one screenshot or the image you're trying to resize?

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787839/resize-image-proportionally-with-css) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5):

If your image is smaller than the screen, it will use the image width. If it is bigger, it uses max-width. So assuming your image is smaller than the display, you want to change your "max-width" to "width" to increase the image size.

```
<div id="banner"><img src="resources/img/banner.png" id="myImage"></div>

#banner{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#myImage{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: @JoseMagana, i hope it so ;)

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property background:cover will help you!

```
html { 
 background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Cover will extend your background to full screen.

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Tricks has the best solution for this that I could find

```html
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Link to CSS-Tricks for the source and original code: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Consider adding a link to the original source where you found this solution so that they can be properly cited/credited.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to link to your stylesheet? I was just having this issue, then I realized that I forgot to link to the CSS and *face-palm*.

Answer (score -1):

You have to give the id banner a specific width that is less than 100%. You don't need a height, it already is automatic. You have to target the image inside the banner and not the class added to the image. So it should look like this:

```
<div id="banner"><img src="resources/img/banner.png" class="myImage"></div>

#banner{
    width: 60%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#banner img{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```