# How to trim off Image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Ok, here is the problem, my app allow users to insert any image. It is up to them insert very big or very long image. But when I rentder image I want the `width="50px"` and `height="100px"`.

ok if I do

```
.myImage{
   width:50px;
   height:100px;
}
```

then the image could be distorted cos the proportion is not accurate. So, here is what I think. First I want the image to have `width:50px` then if the `height>100px`, then CSS will trim off the bottom. 
Ok, let see this example, user inserted a big image with `width=150px` and `height=600px`. So if I reduce the width to `50px`, the the height will be `200px`. I want to cut the bottom of the image so it will show only `(w: 50px, h: 100px)` see the picture:

[image]

So how to do that?

Comment: It would be better to crop the image in the upload process - If you're scaling/cropping down large images via CSS you're load speeds are going to suffer. However if you don't care about that, you could wrap the image in a div at the desired size with `overflow: hidden` set, or set it as a background image and change the background position.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize image proportionally with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787839/resize-image-proportionally-with-css)

Comment: Use background-image css property instead img tag. (Of course if img is not part of design and you don't have to be semantic :))

Comment: I think you have to generate a thumbnail. What technology are you using?

Comment: I set maxsize= 1 mb, so if a image is very big then it will be very blur

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1) Trim image with `<div>` and `overflow:hidden`:

```
 div.trim {
     max-height:100px;
     max-width: 50px;
     overflow: hidden;
 }

 <div class="trim"><img src="veryBigImage.png"/></div>
```

2) Use `max-width: 50px;` and `max-height: 100px` for image itself. So image will preserve it's dimensions

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest using the [CSS CLIP](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) property to trim it to the size you want.

```
img {
position: absolute;
clip: rect(0px,50px,100px,0px);
width:50px;
}
```

That way, if the image is small enough, nothing will get cut off. Otherwise, you trim it down.

Comment: `clip` is now deprecated in favor of `clip-path`.

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap the `img` with a `div` and apply `overflow: hidden;`

HTML:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="path/to/image.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrapper{
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img-wrapper img{
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using max-width and max-height you can set height to whatever you want and the full image will display.

```
.myImage{
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    max-width:300px;
    max-height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the image in a container of the desired trim size with `overflow:hidden`

html:

```
<div id="container"><img src="myimage.jpg"/></div>
```

css:

```
#container {width:50px;height:100px;overflow:hidden}
#container img {width:50px;}
```