# How to not display part of an image that falls outside its div

Tags: css

I have a div with the form of a circle and a square image in that div. I would like the parts of the image that fall outside of the div, to not be displayed (so not resize the image or make a circle out of the image; but instead not show its parts outside the circled div). How can I achieve this with CSS?

I have the following:

```
<div className="divimage">
    <img src="image.jpg"/>
</div>

.divimage {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 25px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;  //I need this for the carousel to work in which I'm using this
    position: relative;
    img {
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trim off Image in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101774/how-to-trim-off-image-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.divimage {
    /* ... */
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Also, you can't nest CSS `selectors`, so extract the `img` declaration.