# Resizing the image proportionally and positioning it center

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to show the image in full page and if the size of the browser window reduces, the image should resize proportionally.

I should be able to get the image to center of the page when browser size reduces.

I have tried something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rwndprm/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://yournaperville.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/disney-world.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
 margin: 0;
}
html{
  background-color: #666666;
}
img { 
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
}
div{
 height: auto;  
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
}
```

I am not sure how far I am right. can anyone help me

Comment: Take a look at the css `zoom` tag. Works like charm, actually.

Comment: Change img width to min-width: 100%;

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787839/resize-image-proportionally-with-css?rq=1

Comment: @JPrakash i think the proportional resize works as said in that question. I also need the image to be in center when size reduces

Answer (score 0):

change img height to 100% and overflow:hidden to html. Works for me!

Comment: I don want to expand the image vertically when browser size is reduced. hope u read my use case