# Display Multiple images from JSON using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code that takes data in the form of json and it looks like this

```js
function json2array() {

  var data = {"images": [

  "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/rg6j1l9iqd-0078915030900.jpg",

  "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/835ggkjjq0-0078915030900.png",

  "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/8fn652ptobh3ecw886.jpg",

  "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/26naopw9flteq3qrcs.jpg",

  "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/uhqq6sdj47-0078915030900.jpg"

]};

  var keys = Object.keys(data);

  keys.forEach(function(key) {

    result.push(data[key]);



  });

  $("#myElement #images").append($('<img>', {
    src: result[key]
  }));

  //  return result;

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="myElement">
    <img id="images"> </img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cjkfgjv9/

To dynamically change src of an image element use this jQuery syntax:

```
$(selector).attr('src', imageUrl);
```

Comment: Check this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cjkfgjv9/3/ . User style tag like this in image: <img id="images1" style="width: 50px; height: 50px"> </img>

Answer (score 1):

You could use, `.each()` function from `jQuery` as shown below.

```
$.each(data.images, function(index, element) {
    alert(element); 
});
```

And IMHO since you are also appending the returned images you ought to name the function likewise, just to avoid the confusion later.

so your function becomes

```
function appendReturnedImages(data) {

  $.each(data.images, function(index, element) {
    $("#myElement #images").append($('<img>', {
      src: element
    }));
  });
}
```

Also the DOM element that you are appending to is an `img`, since an `img` cant contain other `img`, you have to make it a `div` as below.

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="myElement">
 <div id="images"> </div>
</div>
```

Edit:- Since I didnt have the returned JSON dataset, I didnt have the chance to test my solution, but it should work, just try fiddling a little bit if it doesnt.

Comment: It worked out perfectly. I have one last question. I have retrieved images but they are coming from a server and their resolution is different. So, I want to resize the images to one particular size like 200 x 200

Comment: You could use `css` to resize the images and if you want a much deeper solution then you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787839/resize-image-proportionally-with-css

Comment: And also, I'd like to mention that you can always create a new question, if you are having a new problem, this is a Q & A site, not a forum.