# Resizing background image in CSS

Tags: css, resize

I need to resize my background "Image.png" to be 112 x 22 pixels, but when I modify `width` and `height`, it crops the image to the size provided instead of resizing it.
How can I *resize* the image in CSS?

```css
#Title-1 {
  width: 148px;
  height: 29px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-image: url("/pic/Image.png");
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: since you are using the image as a **CSS background**, not as an inline image (`<img src=...>`), take a look at [this reference answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background) and the CSS property `background-size`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize image proportionally with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787839/resize-image-proportionally-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you modify the `width` and `height` values, you are actually changing those values for the container.

You'll want to add this to your CSS:

```
#Title-1 {
    background-size: 112px 22px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `background-size` option?

```
background-size: 112px 22px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it now,

And I solved it by using:

```
background-size:cover
```

Thank you all.