# Flexbox: overflow of img in IE 11

Tags: css, flexbox

The following code works in all modern browsers that I've tested (safari, chrome and firefox) except internet explorer. I'm trying to vertically and horizontally center an image inside `logo`. The problem is that the `img` overflows the container which is 50px 50px. If I remove flexbox from the css, the image does not overflow, but then it is no longer centered.

I've had a look at [Flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) to try and solve the issue. But no luck. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

html

```
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <section class="post">
        <div class="post-header">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="#" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.content {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.logo {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Please post a demo.

Comment: @Paulie_D The images are all of different sizes. I've specified the height and width of the container so they automatically resize.

Comment: Here's your code with a 400x400 image. Not overflowing in IE11. https://jsfiddle.net/smk2bq8z/3/

Comment: @Michael_B I was just putting together a demo. You are right. I tried your fiddle in Ie and it works so it must be something else lurking around in my code. Many thanks.

Comment: @Michael_B I figured out what the real problem was. It had to do with max-height, max-width. I amended my css by looking at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787839/resize-image-proportionally-with-css) Appreciate the help.