# resize picture but still has to be responsive

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I hava A image in a slider.
it is responsive but the image is to big.

How can i resize it? (but it has to stay responsive)

```
   <img src="switch/3.jpg"  class="homeImg">
```

.homeImg{
    width: 100%;

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize image proportionally with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787839/resize-image-proportionally-with-css)

Comment: myabe you can use CSS `cover` ?

Comment: can you please copy the slider code? to set image width: 100% you have to set the container width too. Then the image it will be resized to its container

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `width: 100%; height: auto;`. This literally means: set the width of the image to 100% of the page width and maintain its aspect ratio.