# How can i resize an image in a block display? (javascript or react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a game, where I need a block of elements to be in line like on the following image. My problem is that the image (kangoroo) is appearing like this.

The real image size is `width:70px` and `height:100px`.

And I wanted to resize it to `width: 49px` and `height: 70px`.

I want to resize it in code because I'm using the normal size on another part of the code. I tried a lot of stuff but nothing works.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Game.js  (some of the code)

```
import React from "react";
import "./Game.css";
import MatchedCard from "../MatchedCard/MatchedCard"
import imagem1 from "../../cardimages/1.jpg";
import imagem2 from "../../cardimages/2.jpg";
import imagem3 from "../../cardimages/3.jpg";

    renderImage(cardType) {
            switch(cardType) {
            case 'A':
              return <img src={imagem1} alt="Raposa"/>;
            case 'B':
              return <img src={imagem2} alt="Cobra"/>;
            case 'C':
              return <img src={imagem3} alt="Galinha"/>;
        // and so on...

    renderMatchedCardTable() {
      return this.state.matchedcardArray.map((matchedcard, index) => {
        const { cardType, cardState, isDisabled } = matchedcard;
        return (
          <MatchedCard
            key={index}
            cardType={cardType}
            cardState={cardState}
            isDisabled={isDisabled}
        />
      );
    });
  }

render() {
    return (

    <div className="Table-wrapper">
        <div className="GameRectangle3">{this.renderMatchedCardTable()}</div>
```

MatchedCard.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./MatchedCard.css";

const MatchedCard = ({ cardState}) => (
  <div className="matchedcard">
  <div className="matchedcardState">{cardState}</div>
  </div>
);

export default MatchedCard;
```

MatchedCard.css

```
.matchedcard{
float:left;
display:block;
width:49px;
height:70px;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 2px;
background-color: #afafaf;
  }

 .matchedcardState{
  font-size: 8px;
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize image proportionally with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787839/resize-image-proportionally-with-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set `width` and `height` properties directly on the `<img />` element in HTML like this:

```
renderImage(cardType) {
  switch(cardType) {
    case 'A':
      return <img src={imagem1} alt="Raposa" width="49px" height="70px"/>;
    case 'B':
      // ...
  }
}
```

Then, to avoid repeating the same width and height for every image, you could abstract the generation of the `<img />` element into a separate function, for example.

Comment: Alternatively, store a list of objects with `type`, `src` and `alt` attributes (or use other names that are more appropriate. Then `map()` over the list to create `<img>` elements.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice how to write that map()? That's seems interesting to me. A answer with more details would be great!

Comment: @TelmoPina That's an answer to a different question than the one you posted here. I suggest you look at other examples of `map()` and post a new question if you still need help.